# Example about the main result on the "New Decomposition For Square Matrices" given by Sir Julio Benitez?

Tags: linear-algebra

can you give a specific example about the main result on the "New Decomposition For Square Matrices" given by Sir Julio Benitez? I really need it. please?

Comment: For those looking for the article, it can be found [here as a PDF.](http://www.math.technion.ac.il/iic/ela/ela-articles/articles/vol20_pp207-225.pdf) I don't have the time to read through it but perhaps someone else can give their input.